# putting 2 f beside each other makes a space on pdf file

Tags: spacing

In any words when 2 *f* are beside each other (like different), on pdf file it makes a space between those *fs* specially inside equations. Any idea please?

like: *diffusion*, i get *dif fusion*

Comment: Inside an equation you should use `\text{diffusion}` or define an operator.

Comment: No idea at all without seeing the code. Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. EDIT: That is, I am taking you at your word when you say 'in any words'. If it is *only* in maths mode, see Gonzalo Medina's answer.

Comment: I used \text{diffusion}, and it worked. Thanks

Comment: The math italic font has wide spaces (for all letters not just f) so that adjacent letters do _not_ look like a word but an implied product of 1-letter variables.

Comment: I am trying to make this formula: d[x]/dt =Synthesis(Production)±Diffusion/Signaling−Degradation. Those terms are all general stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\text` macro from `amsmath` so that the fonts are properly selected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  x &= y \quad some times they are different \\
  x &= y \quad \text{some times they are different} \\
  x &= y \quad\text{not a diffusion equation}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As per the comment, this is what may be needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  d[x]/dt &= \text{Synthesis (Production) $\pm$ Diffusion $/$ Signaling $-$ Degradation} \\
  \frac{\mathrm{d}[x]}{\mathrm{d}t} &= \frac{\text{Synthesis (Production) $\pm$ Diffusion }}
            {\text{Signaling $-$ Degradation}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: in fact, diffusion is not a text. It is part of equation like: d[x]/dt =Synthesis(Production)±Diffusion/Signaling−Degradation

Comment: @Maryam I have updated the answer.